# Constraint Check has to be one or the other

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pretty new to SQL, however I am creating tables.

I need to ensure that the column `Type` is either `Available` or `Unavailable` can only be entered. I am not sure if `CHECK` constraint is correct:

```
CONSTRAINT Delivery Driver Type,
CHECK (Delivery Driver Type in Available, Unavailable)
```

Or if there is any other Oracle code to use? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you think there's any possibility that in future you may want more than the two values for `delivery_driver_type` you should consider using a lookup table instead, with a foreign key constraint joining the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name
ADD CONSTRAINT Cnt_Delivery_Driver_Type
CHECK (Delivery_Driver_Type IN ('Available', 'Unavailable'));
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2781b/1/0)**</kbd>

Your table names shouldn't contain spaces because it is bad practice. If you need spaces quote them with backtick `MariaDB/MySQL`, square brackets `SQL Server`, `"` Oracle.

Comment: thanks, however - I'm still doing my degree and database is my first subject, but this really helps though thanks!!!!

Comment: Actually `"` is what the standard defines to quote identifiers. It's not specific to Oracle. And the standard quoting can be used in the other DBMS as well if configured properly